# How to merge multiple files into single file in given directories

Tags: shell-script, cat

I want to write a shell script to merge contents of multiple files in a given directories.

```
DIR1 contains sample1.txt sample2.txt
    sample1.txt contents  :---this is sample1 file---
    sample2.txt contents  :---this is sample2 file---

DIR2 contains demo1.txt demo2.txt
    demo1.txt contents  :---this is demo1 file---
```

I tried the solution :

```
(find /home/DIR1  /home/DIR2 -type f | xargs -i cat {} ) > /result/final.txt
```

I got the output as well but sequence of file has changed.

```
this is sample2 file---  this is sample1 file---  this is demo1 file---
```

I need every file's output ina different line . how to do this?
Is there any way to maintain the order of files output like If i want to place particular file's output at the top or so?
and what is the use of `" xargs -i "` option in the cmd?

Thanks.

Comment: Which files you're trying to merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
(find directory -type f | xargs -i cat {} ) > TOTAL
```

Looks for all files in directory and puts all content in TOTAL.

Comment: I need to merge contents in a given file's order what should I add to the above cmd?

Comment: Please, add an example about this, because it is not clear what you expect.

Comment: I have modified the above code please check

Comment: above command worked but it doesn't add new file's contents to new line how to acheive the same?

Answer (score 2):

You need to go directly into that directory:

```
cat /home/me/mydir/* > /home/me/finalData.txt
```

Comment: No i can't i am writitng shell script

Comment: @ashwini What do you mean? Can you share your script then?

Comment: I have to write a shell script which will run from different [base]location other than /home/me/mydir/ location.